# generating a pdf file with utf8 characters with mpdf

Tags: utf-8, phpmailer, mpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf file with mpdf and send it by e-mail.
The file is written in both english and hebrew.
I've got the file to be created correctly when I open it on the browser (with `$mpdf->output()`):
[this is how it lloks like when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDZ5L.png)
 but then when I try opening it with the pdf viewer or when I try sending it with php mailer with addStringAttachment($stringAttachment , filename.pdf) all the hebrew comes out as just a bunch of rectangles:
[this is how it looks when it doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p32HM.png)
this is my code:

```
    <?php
//$htmlResult is set to be the pdf page - written in html.

$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8' , 'A4-P');

$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlResult);
$fileName = "report".$formatedFromDate.'-'.$formatedToDate;
$mpdf->Output("1234.pdf" , "D");
```

when I try to send it with phpMailer:

```
$stringPdf = $mpdf->Output("1234.pdf" , "S");
$body = " ";
$subject = $fileName;

FunctionPool::sendEmail($emailAddress, $body, $subject , $stringPdf ,$fileName);
```

and the function sendMail:

```
public static function sendEmail ($emailAddress , $body , $subject , $stringAttachments = NULL , $fileName = NULL) {


        //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
        //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');
        require_once __DIR__.'/variables.php';
        require_once __DIR__.'/PHPMailerMaster/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require_once __DIR__.'/PHPMailerMaster/class.phpmailer.php';
        require_once __DIR__.'/PHPMailerMaster/class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php';
        require_once __DIR__.'/settings.php';
        //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
        $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
        $mail->isSMTP();

        //Enable SMTP debugging
        // 0 = off (for production use)
        // 1 = client messages
        // 2 = client and server messages
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        if (1 != $underDevelopment) {
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        }

        //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
        $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

        //Set the hostname of the mail server
        //$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

        // use
        $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
        // if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
        //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
        $mail->Port = 587;
        //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        //Whether to use SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        //$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;        
        $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
            'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
            )
        );


        //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
        $serversEmailAddress = **************@gmail.com";
        $serversEmailPassword = "**************";
        $systemsName = "**************";

        $mail->Username = $serversEmailAddress;
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $mail->Password = $serversEmailPassword;
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $mail->setFrom($serversEmailAddress , $systemsName);
        //Set an alternative reply-to address
        $mail->addReplyTo($serversEmailAddress, $systemsName);
        //Set who the message is to be sent to
        $mail->addAddress($emailAddress);
        //Set the subject line
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
        //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
        $mail->msgHTML($body/*file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__)*/);
        //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';



        if ($stringAttachments != NULL) {
            if ($fileName == NULL) {
                $fileName = "report";
            }
            $mail->addStringAttachment($stringAttachments , $fileName.".pdf");
        }

        //send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            echo "error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
            return "sent";
        }
    }
```

When I send an e-mail with a pdf attached (also in hebrew) it works just fine.
I thought I'd save a temp file, and then send it, but then I discovered that I can view the file proparly only from the browser.

Comment: PHPMailer doesn't touch the contents of attachments, it just makes sure they use an appropriate transfer-encoding. You should receive exactly what you put in. Do both actions at the same time with the same content and do a binary diff on the files to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Thanks.  
It doesn't make a difference how I generate the file (with the flags "S","F" or "D") it shows fine on the web browser (firefox) but shows rectangulars on the ubuntu pdf viewer, android office suite and gmail pdf viewer. (I haven't tryed any other ways to open it, but I think it's enough of a problem this way...)

Comment: My "solution": I stopped using mpdf, and using now tcpdf.  works like a charm!